# Добавление готовых библиотек в проект под NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

В проекте под Android NDK есть ряд готовых библиотек. Если их добавлять в проект таким образом:

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_LIBS := libfirst.so ... liblast.so

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

то они не копируются в папку libs/armeabi. Хотя тот же самый make отлично работает во время сборки внутри исходников андроида. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что скрипт ndk-build не поддерживает `LOCAL_PREBUILT_LIBS` и `BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT`. Это можно проверить, посмотрев справку `($NDK_ROOT)/docs/*.TXT` - там не описаны эти возможности.

Чтобы использовать сторонние библиотеки, можно прописать пути к ним прямо в `LOCAL_LDLIBS`.