# Как добавить динамически подгружаемые библиотеки?

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

Есть ряд предварительно собранных библиотек `lib*.so`. Как их добавить в поставку при сборке через NDK? [Обычный метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1804/) (`LOCAL_PREBUILT_LIBS` и `BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT`), который используется в полной системе сборки андроида, для NDK не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно просто скопировать so-библиотеки в папку libs/armeabi, а потом подгружать динамически через вызовы dlopen/dlclose, то можно поменять make-файл.

```
SO_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs
SO := libsomething.so

# Это взято из скриптов ndk-build
# При сборке будут предупреждения о переопределении - их можно игнорировать
$(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE): $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE) $(SO) clean-installed-binaries
    $(hide) mkdir -p $(PRIVATE_DST_DIR)
    @ echo "Install        : $(PRIVATE_NAME) => $(PRIVATE_DST_DIR)"
    $(hide) install -p $(PRIVATE_SRC) $(PRIVATE_DST)
    $(hide) $(call cmd-strip, $(PRIVATE_DST))

$(SO): 
    @ echo "Install        : $@ => $(PRIVATE_DST_DIR)"
    $(hide) install -p $(SO_PATH)/$@ $(PRIVATE_DST_DIR)
```

Когда будет собираться apk, просто скопированные so-файлы упакуются вместе с собранными.